# align multiline text at start and end in a textview android

Tags: android

3 line text should display like this -

ExclusiveLane Terracotta La-
ntern Handpainted Table lamp
From

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_title_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/product_title_margin_left"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/product_title_margin_top"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:textColor="@color/wishlist_title_color" />
```

Comment: this text is static or dynamic you have shown?

Comment: dynamic text that will come from server

Comment: How is it displaying now? What isn't right about it?